# Best Lightweight Linux distro for Minecraft Bedrock Server on MacBook Pro 10,1 (early 2013)

Tags: linux, macbook

I’ve been successfully running a Minecraft Bedrock Server on a MacMini and, more recently, on a spare MacBook Pro 10,1 for a few years using the Docker itzg image. However, with Minecraft updates and increasing hardware demands, my server is becoming somewhat laggy. To address this, I’m considering removing the macOS and Docker layers from my setup and running the server directly on Linux.

I have some experience running a small Ubuntu Server on a Raspberry Pi for various tasks like Pi-hole, proxies, Bluetooth audio, Discord bots, etc. However, for my Minecraft Server, I want to maximize performance by using a more stripped-down distribution. Alpine and Void Linux have caught my attention as minimal distributions focused on resource efficiency.

I attempted to install Void Linux, but after a few hours of struggling, I couldn’t create a USB or SD card that the Void installer could fully read. I used 'dd' to create the installation media, but I encountered various I/O errors during the installation process. Notably, these same SD cards and USB drives work flawlessly on macOS and my Ubuntu server.

So, my primary question is whether it’s possible to install a working command-line interface (CLI) Linux distribution on a MacBook Pro Retina (early 2013). I prefer to just SSH to it so I guess I only need a working network adapter (which is a Thunderbolt port with an ethernet dongle). Additionally, I’d appreciate recommendations on the best lightweight Linux distribution for utilizing aging hardware effectively for running a Minecraft Bedrock Server.

Cheers.